# Modify Legend of plot with several variables (colour, shape, fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to build a scatterplot using ggplot2.

However, I have some issue with renaming the legend. I would like to have "Spelling conditions" instead of "spelling" and "Lowercase", "Uppercase" instead of "lower","upper".

After some readings, I tried simultaneously the scale_fill_discrete()+  scale_ colour_discrete() and  scale_shape_discrete() in order to get only 1 legend box, however using this method, my legend disappeared completely !

```
RT.data <- read.csv("http://www.psy.gla.ac.uk/~christop/MScStats/2015/Regress/RTs.csv")
head(RT.data)


x <- RT.data$logfreq
y <- RT.data$RT


ggplot(RT.data, aes(x, y, colour=spelling, shape=spelling)) +
geom_point() +

geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE,level=0.95, aes(fill=spelling) ,alpha=0.09)+

ggtitle("Scatterplot of RT as a function  \n of log lexical frequency and spelling of words :")+


scale_colour_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
             breaks=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase"),
             labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) + 

scale_fill_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
             breaks=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase"),
             labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +

scale_shape_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
             breaks=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase"),
             labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +

ylab("RT(ms)") +
xlab("Log lexical frequency") +

theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray", size= 1, fill = "gray99"),
     legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
     legend.position="top",
     axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",colour="sienna",size=16),
     axis.title.x =element_text(size=16,face="bold", colour= "sienna"),
     plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.9, face="bold",size=16))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
library(ggplot2)

RT.data <- read.csv("http://www.psy.gla.ac.uk/~christop/MScStats/2015/Regress/RTs.csv")
x <- RT.data$logfreq
y <- RT.data$RT

ggplot(RT.data, aes(x, y, colour=spelling, shape=spelling)) +

geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE,level=0.95,alpha=0.09, aes(fill=spelling) )+
ggtitle("Scatterplot of RT as a function  \n of log lexical frequency and spelling of words :")+
scale_colour_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
                      breaks=c("lower", "upper"),
                      labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +
ylab("RT(ms)") +
xlab("Log lexical frequency") +
guides(shape=FALSE, fill =F)+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray", size= 1, fill = "gray99"),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
      legend.position="top",
      axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",colour="sienna",size=16),
      axis.title.x =element_text(size=16,face="bold", colour= "sienna"),
      plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.9, face="bold",size=16))
```

Comment: Hi Mamoun, Thanks for the try. The legend is there indeed but not in the format I would like unfortunately...

Comment: What is your desired format ? can you provide an image or a link to desired legend ...?

Comment: I am happy with the format, it's the content I am trying to change. Instead of "spelling" , I would like to have : "Spelling conditions" . And instead of "lower" and "upper", I would like to have  "Lowercase" and "Uppercase" . Thanks !

Comment: I have edited the answer by adding `guides(shape=FALSE)` and used `scale_colour_discrete`

Comment: Thank you so much ! Thanks to you, I am almost there ! My last issue now is that the legends have a grey background instead of pink and blue (as seen on the plot). I know the 95% CI background are coloured by the "Fill" parameter but this add an extra/separate legend so I have removed it using guides(fill=FALSE). Is there a way to merge the legend so the fill are shown in red & blue instead of gray ?  Here is my script below (sorry didn't know how to add it in a nicer way)

Comment: install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("daattali/ggExtra")
library("ggExtra")                                     p <- ggplot(RT.data, aes(x, y, colour=spelling,shape=spelling,fill=spelling)) +geom_point() +geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE,level=0.95,alpha=0.08)+geom_rug(size=0.1)+scale_colour_discrete(name="Spelling conditions", breaks=c("lower", "upper"),  labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +
ggtitle("Linear Regression (95% CI) of RT as a function of\n log lexical frequency and spelling of words :") +ylab("RT (ms)") +xlab("Log lexical frequency") +guides(shape=FALSE,fill=FALSE)

Comment: +theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray", size= 1, fill = "gray99"), legend.background = element_rect(size=.3, linetype="dotted"),legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1), axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",colour="sienna",size=16),axis.title.x =element_text(face="bold", colour= "sienna",size=16),plot.title = element_text(face="bold",size=20))

Comment: ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram",fill ="indianred1",yparams=list(size=0.5,binwidth = 10), xparams = list(fill = "paleturquoise2",binwidth = 0.1))

Comment: if this works, you should post it as answer instead of comment

Comment: It's your solution in my newest code which is why I didn't include it as a question. I still have a slight issue which the legend. Indeed, in the legend, the 95% interval are shown as grey instead of red and blue respectively. Any idea how to change this ? Thanks

Comment: of course, I have edited my answer, if this works, consider accepting it.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

By slightly modifying Mamoun Benghezal answer, I can have 1 legend including colour and shape, fill together with the categories renamed :

```
ggplot(RT.data, aes(logfreq, RT,colour=spelling,shape=spelling,fill=spelling)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE,level=0.99,alpha=0.09)+

ggtitle("Linear Regression (99% CI) of RT as a function of log Lexical \n Frequency and spelling conditions of words :") +
ylab("RT (ms)\n") +
xlab("\nLog lexical frequency") +

scale_colour_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
                  breaks=c("lower", "upper"),
                  labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +

scale_fill_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
                  breaks=c("lower", "upper"),
                  labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +

scale_shape_discrete(name="Spelling conditions",
                  breaks=c("lower", "upper"),
                  labels=c("Lowercase", "Uppercase")) +  


theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray", size= 1, fill= "gray99"),
  legend.background = element_rect(size=0.05),
  legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1),
  axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",colour="pink4",size=16),
  axis.title.x =element_text(face="bold", colour= "palevioletred3",size=16),
  plot.title = element_text(face="bold",size=18))
```